# How to scaling the equation in math mode

Tags: matrices

Note that we cannot use the /small to the math mode.
I want use the `/resizebox`, but it is not work with some environment. For example LaTeX editor show that it is a wrong code by the color.

[image]

However,

```
\begin{equation}
\resizebox{!}{!}{ a+b }
\end{equation}
```

is work. Why?
What is good solution for my problem; the major problem is matrices increases the volume of the article.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the package `adjustbox` for the tag `\resizebox` and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\resizebox{!}{!}{$a+b$}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

But scaling the `equation` is not such a good idea, better to reduce the font size, refer the below `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
a+b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\resizebox{!}{!}{$a+b$}
\end{equation}

\begin{small}
\begin{equation}
a+b
\end{equation}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

If `matrix` are the only the issue, then you can try with `smallmatrix` and the `MWE` is:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{smallmatrix}
...\\
....
\end{smallmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: No, the second suggestion is wrong: the vertical spacing goes awry.

Answer (score 1):

`\resizebox` puts its contents in text mode, which fails if it contains math-like constructions.

- The first equation fails because `bmatrix` creates an `array` with delimiters, which requires math mode. So it will succeed when using

  ```
  \begin{equation}
    \resizebox{!}{!}{$\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \end{bmatrix}$}
  \end{equation}
  ```
- The second equation doesn't fail because `a+b` can be written in both text and math mode.

Resizing isn't always best. Perhaps consider transposing vertical (or column-like) matrices so they become horizontal (or row-like).